# Privoxy filter to block YouTube ads

Tags: privoxy

Is there any filter for Privoxy to block Youtube video ads? I've searched the whole web, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As you can see here](http://sourceforge.net/p/ijbswa/support-requests/1633/#d2fd), Privoxy can't filter encrypted content, and Youtube resources are now only served over such secure connections.

If a local extension is enough for your needs, you may like [uBlock](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock#-%C2%B5block), a new ad blocker that is much more efficient and lightweight than Adblock Plus. It blocks Youtube ads by default.

Comment: thank you. I am already using uBlock, it's fantastic, but I wanted something network-wide solution which works on my mobile devices too. As I see, there is no universal solution at this moment.

Comment: Actually you have a few options here. You can use https://www.stunnel.org which automatically makes a pem file for you and all you need todo is create your config and have it forward requests from 443 to 8181 (privoxy).

You can also use this python SSL proxy (http://prxbx.com/forums/showthread.php?tid=1618&page=15) and do the samething.

Answer (score 0):

adblockplus https://adblockplus.org/ works for me. If you open blockable items it will show you what filters were used to filter what content. You could copy some filters over to Privoxy.

I think it's mainly these 2 files:

https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_companion_ad.js
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js